# Matlab: parsing large segmented data with empty strings

Tags: matlab, parsing

I have a complex data text file to parse, my first problem is some of the strings values are missing (such as row 5 column 4 shown in Data below, I tried using `treatAsEmpty` with 8 blank spaces but it didn't work it keeps moving the `B` from the 5th row over and not registering the rest of the row [To be honest I don't need that column, if you can show me how to ignore it that would solve this problem]).

```
textscan(fileName .'%4d %4d %4d %8s \t %1s %2d \b %2s %7s %5d %*[^\n]','delimiter','\r','treatAsEmpty','        ','EmptyValue',-Inf);
```

Data:

```
0439 0444 0441 S09E44SF                       A 13    ES 3.7E-04 10230
0727 0736 0732 S27W23SF                       A 29    ES 1.2E-03 10226
0937 0945 0942 S29W16SF                       A 23    ES 8.8E-04 10226
2000 2016 2008 S28W27SF                       C 23    ES 1.8E-03 10226
2134 2217 2153                                B 27    ES 4.8E-02 10229

0032 0042 0037 S25W27SF                       C 45    ES 2.1E-03 10226
0142 0147 0145 S09E35SF                       C 14    ES 4.1E-04 10230
0536 0555 0541 S09E33SF                       C 16    ES 1.6E-03 10230

0214 0312 0252 N23W422F                       A 11    ES 2.3E-02 10223
```

My second problem is, the blank space that is row 6 and row 10. I need to get rows 1-5 in cells (1x9), rows 7-9 in cells (2x9), row 11 in cells (3x9), etc.

Comment: you can read it line by line with 'fgetl' and throw it into a cell array by 'strsplit'.